# BadYieldError when using find() Motor [MongoDB + Tornado]

Tags: python, json, mongodb, tornado-motor

I am new to python tornado framework. I have a small collection of data in MongoDB. I am using a simple get function in my python file. I get a `BadYieldError` when using the `db.collection.find()` option. But `db.collection.find_one()` works fine but it display only one record.

```
import tornado
import bson
from bson import json_util
from bson.json_util import dumps
class TypeList(APIHandler):
@gen.coroutine
def get(self):
    doc = yield db.vtype.find()
    self.write(json_util.dumps(doc))
```

The error is:

> tornado.gen.BadYieldError: yielded unknown object MotorCursor()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`find` returns a `MotorCursor`. Yield the cursor's `fetch_next` property to advance the cursor and call `next_object()` to retrieve the current document:

```
@gen.coroutine
def do_find():
    cursor = db.test_collection.find({'i': {'$lt': 5}})
    while (yield cursor.fetch_next):
        document = cursor.next_object()
        print document
```

Please refer to the tutorial section [Querying for More Than One Document](http://motor.readthedocs.org/en/stable/tutorial.html#querying-for-more-than-one-document) for instructions on using Motor's `find` and `MotorCursor`.

Comment: can you tell me how I can return the value to the browser? Because when I `return document` instead of `print document` it gives me TypeError: Expected none got....
And when I use `self.write(document)` it gives me `TypeError: ObjectId('55a5e988545779f35d3ecdf4') is not JSON serializable`

Comment: RequestHandlers use self.write to send bytes to the user. "from bson import json_util" at the top of your Python module, and then something like (untested) `docs = yield cursor.to_list(None); self.write(json_util.dumps({'docs': docs}).encode())`.